# bash: Expand list of arguments and pass it to find - escaping/white spaces hell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find, escaping

I want to check a folder for files and delete some of them. One condition is to keep all files of a certain type (e.g. *.txt) and also keep all files with the names of the first search but with different extensions ([names of first search].*). All other files in the directory should be deleted.

This can easily be achieved by the `find . -type f -not -name xxx` command. However, I would like to populate the find command for each [name of first search] found automatically.

To do so I wrote this litte script

```
#!/bin/bash

while read filename; do
     filename=$(echo $filename | sed 's/\ /\\\ /g')
     filename=\'$filename*\'
     file_list=$file_list" -not -name $filename"
done <<<"$(ls *.txt | sed 's/.txt//g')"

find . -type f $file_list -print0| while read -d $'\0' FILE
     do
     rm -f "$FILE"
done
```

The $file_list is nicely populated with the respective data, however, find fails saying:

> find: unknown predicate `-\'

in case I use the sed command (' ' -> '\ ') or

> find: paths must precede expression: - Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P]
>   [-Olevel] [-D [help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...]
>   [expression]

if I comment the sed line.

bash -x shows me the following executed command:

without the sed command:

> find . -type f -not -name ''\''Text' - here - or - there*'\'''

with the sed command:

> find . -type f -not -name ''\''Text\' '-\' 'here\' '-\' 'or\'
>   'there*'\'''

Is this even possible with find? I also tried escaping `$find_list` in the find command with no success.

Comment: Feel free to take a look at [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155551/how-to-debug-a-bash-script/155553#155553).

Comment: You cannot get quotes into a string argument to [work that way](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). But you don't need to. Quote the variable expansion and it will be one argument to the command that is being run. Also [don't parse the output from ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) just use a glob (with `echo` in this case or don't bother with the `read` loop and just use a `for` loop over the glob `for file in *.txt`).

Comment: Also, `$'\0'` is just a more complicated way to write `''` in bash, since bash stores content in C strings, and NUL bytes terminate C strings. (`-d ''` as an argument to `read` correctly indicates a NUL terminator, since the first byte of a 0-byte string is its NUL terminator).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an array, not a string.

```
#!/bin/bash
# ^-- must be /bin/bash, not /bin/sh, for this to work

excludes=( )
for filename in *.txt; do
  excludes+=( -not -name "${filename%.txt}" )
done

find . -type f -not -name '*.txt' "${excludes[@]}" -exec rm -f '{}' +
```

To understand why this works, see [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

---

Now, if you want to be compatible with `/bin/sh`, not just bash, then encapsulate this in a function so you can overwrite the argument list (which is the only available array) without throwing away the script's global arguments:

```
delete_except_textfiles() {
  local filename 2>/dev/null ||: "local keyword not in POSIX, ignore if not present"
  set --
  for filename in *.txt; do
    set -- "$@" -not -name "${filename%.txt}"
  done
  find . -type f -not -name '*.txt' "$@" -exec rm -f '{}' +
}
delete_except_textfiles
```

Comment: Thanks for your overwhelming answers, guys. As I am going to use the script for bash only, I will use the array solution of Charles Duffy. However, lots of links to read. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
#!/bin/bash

remove_except()
{
    local extension=$( printf "%q" "$1" )
    local dir=$( printf "%q" "$2" )
    local start_dir=$(pwd)

    [ -z "$extension" ] && return 1
    [ -z "$dir" ] || [ ! -d "$dir" ] && dir="."
    cd "$dir"

    local this="$0"
    this="${this##*/}"

    # exclude myself and extension
    local excludes=" -name \"$this\" -o -name \"*.$extension\" "

    for f in *."$extension";
    do
        filename="${f%.*}"
        excludes="$excludes -o -name \"$filename.*\""
    done

    eval "find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -not \( $excludes \) -print0" | xargs -0 -I {} rm -v {}

    cd "$start_dir"
}

remove_except "txt" "/your/dir"
```

Put into a script e.g. `remove_except.sh` and run it like this:

```
remove_except.sh "txt" "/your/dir"
```

The second argument is optional and will assume `.` if not specified.

Comment: Using `eval` without thoroughly safe escaping (such as `printf %q`), and thus providing a path for code to be treated as data, is dangerous -- think about being called as `remove_except 'text$(rm -rf .)foo'`.

Comment: Ok, I agree and hate using eval myself but here if not using arrays ```$excludes``` doesn't get properly expanded i.e. you get extra quotes in debug output like ```find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -not '(' -name '"*.txt"' -o -name '"aaa.*"' -o -name '"bbb.*"' ')'``` instead of ```find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -not '(' -name '*.txt' -o -name 'aaa.*' -o -name 'bbb.*' ')'```

Comment: Backing up and rereading, I get what you were saying, and yes -- if not using arrays, you get string-splitting and glob-expansion but no quote processing, that's correct. However... well, frankly, not using arrays is *wrong* in this use case, in a practice-causes-security-vulnerabilities kind of sense.

Comment: I've amended my answer to cover a mechanism for avoiding bashisms (the only reason I can think of for not using arrays) while still performing this operation in a correct/safe manner.

Comment: (Actually, being called with a malicious string is the less-worrisome case; a malicious filename ending in `.txt` is much more likely to be a genuine vulnerability, if, for instance, we're cleaning up an upload directory).

Comment: Right now, the arguments are escaped, but not the filenames found by the first pass. Those filenames also can be malicious.

Comment: Also, I'd suggest `printf -v extension %q "$1"`. More efficient, less buggy (think about the trailing-whitespace case).

Comment: What about the trailing space?

Comment: Heh. Actually, I was wrong there -- it's only trailing _newlines_ that `$()` discards, and `printf %q` will convert them to `$'\n'` sequences, so that's safe. On the other hand, `start_dir=$(pwd)` *is* buggy, inasmuch as if your directory name ends in a literal newline, it trims that off.

Comment: ...`start_dir=$PWD`, by contrast, avoids both the overhead of the subshell and the misbehavior of modifying the content (in the admittedly very unlikely case of being in a directory name ending in a newline literal).